# How can I send video stream to iOS device via 30-pin dock?

Tags: iphone, ios, dock

I have a customized device made by myself, and I want to use iOS device as a screen to receive video stream from my device.

But I don't want to use the WIFI solution. Because I don't want to add wifi chipset to my device, it's expensive.

So I want to know if I can use the 30-pin dock to do what I need and How to do it.

TIA.

Comment: While it may not be feasible now, using a wifi solution would allow you to stream to *any* device with a wifi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is get into the [MFi program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/). Once in that program you will be able to receive the necessary components for your device that will allow you to communicate with the phone, as well as the necessary tools so you can talk over it, and write software to do it as well.

Comment: Thanks Jer. Do you have any exp on this? I don't know if the MFi program could do this, so I can't decede to apply the MFi program.

Comment: Yes I do. MFi is what you're looking for. Be forewarned though, it's a bit of a bitch, and your organization must have, must have a separate marketing contact. Plus, you will end up pulling out most of your hair during the process, but it's the only way to get access to the little chips you need to communicate with the device legally. So I strongly suggest you just suck up all the headaches, and push forward.